# How to click "OK"on IOS alert box using Appium 1.21.0 on Simulator?

Tags: java, ios, xcode, appium

I'm writing a test using Java & Appium 1.21.0. I'm unable to click "OK" button on alert box to close the popup on the Simulator iPhone.

I tried the following code:

```
Actions action = new Actions(getDriver());
action.moveToElement(getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name=\"OK\"]")));
action.click();
action.perform();
```

The above code is not working.

Using the following:

- Appium 1.21.0
- Xcode 14.0.1 - running simulator iPhone 8

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
caps.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", "true"); // to accept all alerts
```

or

```
caps.setCapability("autoDissmissAlerts", "true"); // to dismiss all alerts
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried them... but it is still not working